# Facing problem with case when statement in a single row fetch for oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a single row of data as follows:

```
dyn1 dyn2 dyn3 chg
   1    0    1 768
```

Now i want  to write a case condition like

```
Case when dyn1 = 1 then 7 When dyn2=1 then 7 When dyn3=1 then 7 End
```

Now for this above records it is not checking the dyn3 value as it is getting dyn1 value as true.

How to handle this code?

Comment: <Case when dyn1 = 1 then 7
    When dyn2=1 then 7
    When dyn3=1 then 7
    End>

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? Of course it doesn't really matter until there is a question that is answerable. I removed all the random database tags. Please add back the one you are actually using.

Comment: Did you want a case statement that returns a single value "7" when dyn1 = "1", AND dyn2 = "1", AND dyn3 = "1"?

Comment: Using oracle sql. I do not have the coe snippest. What is happening actually is i am using case when and when first condition satisfies it is not checking tje second condition.

Comment: I have for this particular row dyn1 column value 1 and also the column dyn3 valur is 1 for this particular record. But as it is getting the first condition true so posting 7 only one times

Comment: My expectation is it will print 7 two times as 1 value present in two columns. Dyn1 and dyn3

Comment: You showed us input. What output, exactly, do you want to get? You said "print 7 two times", but - how? Post it by editing the original question, formatted, not here (as a comment), please.

Comment: Output like two different row for that particular one row.  Row 1 contain Col1 value as 7 and col2 value as chg value and row 2 must contain also exactly the same record

Comment: Edit your original post and show the output you expect as its impossible to discern from your comments I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suppose that you need to return those values in a select statement, maybe this could be helpful to you.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN dyn1 = 1 THEN 7 END,
        CASE WHEN dyn2 = 1 THEN 7 END,
        CASE WHEN dyn3 = 1 THEN 7 END
FROM (SELECT 1 AS dyn1, 1 AS dyn2, 1 AS dyn3 FROM dual);
```

Or, maybe you want it in an only column

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN dyn1 = 1 THEN 7 END ||
        CASE WHEN dyn2 = 1 THEN 7 END ||
        CASE WHEN dyn3 = 1 THEN 7 END
from (select 1 as dyn1, 1 as dyn2, 1 as dyn3 from dual);
```

Comment: But I want two different row not in the same row

Comment: Solved the problem by using the idea of Giovanni Esposito. At first i alligned the result bu comma separated value. And thrn that comma separated values are splitted into different rows by using the pivot and regexp_substr command.